# Updating element in database using a user defined primary key Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I understand that the save() method decides whether it should insert or update depending on whether the primary key is already in the database.

I am using a charField as a primary key.
My problem is that when I try and submit the form it gives an error saying that there already is an element with that primary key in the database, which is what I am testing but it should update that row instead of just throwing an error. So the error is happening in is_valid but I am not sure how to by pass this. Because if I just take that out then it gives an error saying that the data was not validated.

views.py

```
def sxsw(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SXSWForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() :        
        form.save()     
        return redirect('/sxsw/formSubmitted/')
    else:

        print form.errors
else:
    form = SXSWForm()

return render(request, 'sxsw/sxsw.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class SXSWDemo(models.Model):
    SIMULATIONS = (
    ('ABC', 'ABC'), ('Asterix', 'Asterix'), ('Home', 'Home'),
    )
    PET = (
    ('Dog', 'Dog'),('Cat', 'Cat'), ('Fish','Fish'),('Hamster', 'Hamster'),
    )
    COLOR = (
    ('Red', 'Red'), ('Blue', 'Blue'), ('Green', 'Green'), ('Purple', 'Purple'), ('Black', 'Black'), ('White', 'White'),
    )



    firstAndLastName = models.CharField(max_length = 50, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null = True, blank = True) 
    simulation = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = SIMULATIONS) 
    favoritePet = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = PET) 
    favoriteColor = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = COLOR) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firstName
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a distinction between an edit view and a create view. Currently your view is doubling as both a create view and a edit view.

Additionally you appear to be calling the save method on a ModelForm rather than the save method on a model instance. There is a difference.

> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and
>   saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of
>   ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword
>   argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that
>   instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of
>   the specified model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

So you either need to break up your view, or you need to tell the user that the instance already exists and ask him whether to replace it.

### Update

Please note that when using an ORM (and specially django ORM) it's  a good idea to use an auto increment numeric primary key. Your `firstAndLastName` field can be marked as unique.

Comment: How would I validate the form then if I made another view because form.is_valid() will return false since the primary key is already there. Also in the url that you linked I am confused with the line.       a = Article.objects.get(pk=1). Where do they get the pk=1 part because mine would have to be pk="what ever they put in the form"

Comment: As that document shows, you have to pass an instance argument to the form when you are editing

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to get that object because in the documentation it uses (pk=1). which means that it is getting the model with a primary key of 1. But my primary key is one of the fields in my form. If the name(primary key) is not already in the database it should insert but if it is already in the database it should update.

Comment: `pk='firstname_lastname'`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it working by using the document that was linked in the answer although I had to make a dummy element in the database with a primary key of "Dont Delete". Then I followed what was on the document.

Note: SXSWDemo is the Model and SXSWForm is the form for that model.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        obj = SXSWDemo.objects.get(pk="Dont Delete")
        form = SXSWForm(request.POST, instance=obj)

        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()     
            return redirect('/sxsw/formSubmitted/')
        else:
            print form.errors
```